# Fullcalendar with $.cookie not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, jquery-cookie

I have been trying to figure this out, and since I can't find any solution, I created a jsfiddle so someone might be able to help me.

I have fullcalendar with the jquery cookie plugin integrated, so that I can 'cache' the view last used by the user.

It works great on Firefox, Chrome, IE8 in Windows XP, but does not work in IE9 under Windows 7.

The calendar simply does not appear and I get an error saying that "Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'".

Can anyone give me a hand?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ECQA6/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you explored localStorage or sessionStorage? Not a solution to your question, but these options have helped me a lot when dealing with jquery cookies.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. I was hoping to find a solution rather than an alternative, because it seems to work very well in all other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have been able to fix this, so I will let the answer here, just in case someone goes throught the same or a similar issue.

The problem was that I was including a file directly from github, and it was not being handled successfully. Bottom line, next time I won't try to include a file directly from github.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no jQuery method `cookie()`.

You probably mean the method from the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). You need to [include the plugin-script](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md) before using this method.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? It's included. Besides, it works on other browsers.

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw the include…

Comment: No problem, at least it means someone is trying to help. I simply don't get the issue, I am not sure if that might be some incompatibility from IE9 with jquery or the cookie plugin.